# Android phone cannot recognize SRIX4K tags

Tags: android, tags, nfc, rfid

I have some NFC tags (ST cardpro ISO 14443 use chip SRIX4K) and some devices with NFC support (LG GPro, Samsung Galaxy Note 2). I tried using a writer app to read/write info on tag by phone but both phones can not recognize those tags. I tried to use Android Beam to tranfer files between the 2 phones and that works ok.

However, nothing happens when I place the tag near the phone. The tags work ok with St-Link/v2 though.

Does anyone have a solution hwo to access these tags on Android?

Comment: Google did not reveal any useful results to "ST cardpro ISO 14443". Could you give more details on what card/chip that is?

Comment: oh sorry, i forget it, it use chip SRIX4K

Comment: Many apps? Which apps did you use to test? The writer/reader by NXP, or the one by NFC labs? Make sure not to test on top of metal. Make sure the tags are not stacked on top of each other when you test. Plus remove any phone cover just in case. Can you test on other NFC tags that are known to be valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SRIX4K is ISO 14443 Type B (B'?) but uses a proprietary protocol on top of ISO 14443-3 framing.

Android NFC devices seem to have difficulties detecting ISO 14443 Type B tags in general. The reason for this is unclear to me. It could be due to power issues, power-up delays, problems with detecting the tag's modulation, etc. At least with devices based on NXP's PN544 (but it seems this applies to other devices too), only tags that completely follow ISO 14443 Type B (up to and including -4) are supported. Chips, like the SRIX4K, that use a proprietary protocol on top of ISO 14443-3 framing (starting with different anti-collision commands!) are not supported.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try with other, hmmm...NTAG 203 maybe ok?

Comment: @UnokenMouny The NTAG series was specifically designed for use with mobile phones so these chips should read fine.